# Shifting the origin in ruptures.display

Tags: python

I am trying to perform change point detection using the ruptures package. When I use the ruptures.display for plotting, the x axis starts of with 0 as the start point. 
And here is how the plot looks like:

[image]

However, I would like to start with an offset. Therefore I have tried to create a custom display function using the ruptures.display source code. But, I am not able to figure out how to shift the origin.

Below is the main code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("test_flooding.csv") 
Start_time = pd.to_datetime('81028520.26',unit='s')
End_time = pd.to_datetime('81113495.41',unit='s')


#Format the 'Date' column 
data['Time']=data['Time'].astype(str)
#Convert the Date column into a date object
data['Time']=pd.to_datetime(data['Time'],unit='s')

#Selecting a specific range 

data=data[(data['Time']<=End_time)]
data=data[(Start_time <=data['Time'])]
data = data.loc[data['ID'] == "id1"]

#Convert the time series values to a numpy 1D array
points=np.array(data['Signal1_of_ID'])

#RUPTURES PACKAGE
#Changepoint detection with the Pelt search method
start_timestamp = int(time.mktime(Start_time.timetuple()))
model="rbf"
algo = rpt.Pelt(model=model).fit(points)
result = algo.predict(pen=10)
display(points,start_timestamp , result, figsize=(10, 6))
plt.title('Change Point Detection: Pelt Search Method')
plt.show()
```

And here is the custom display code:

```
from itertools import cycle

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from ruptures.utils import pairwise

COLOR_CYCLE = ["#4286f4", "#f44174"]


def display(signal,Start_time, true_chg_pts, computed_chg_pts=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Display a signal and the change points provided in alternating colors. If another set of change
    point is provided, they are displayed with dashed vertical dashed lines.

    Args:
        signal (array): signal array, shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_features).
        true_chg_pts (list): list of change point indexes.
        computed_chg_pts (list, optional): list of change point indexes.

    Returns:
        tuple: (figure, axarr) with a :class:`matplotlib.figure.Figure` object and an array of Axes objects.

    """
    if signal.ndim == 1:
        signal = signal.reshape(-1, 1)
    n_samples, n_features = signal.shape
    # let's set all options
    figsize = (10, 2 * n_features)  # figure size
    alpha = 0.2  # transparency of the colored background
    color = "k"  # color of the lines indicating the computed_chg_pts
    linewidth = 3   # linewidth of the lines indicating the computed_chg_pts
    linestyle = "--"   # linestyle of the lines indicating the computed_chg_pts

    if "figsize" in kwargs:
        figsize = kwargs["figsize"]
    if "alpha" in kwargs:
        alpha = kwargs["alpha"]
    if "color" in kwargs:
        color = kwargs["color"]
    if "linewidth" in kwargs:
        linewidth = kwargs["linewidth"]
    if "linestyle" in kwargs:
        linestyle = kwargs["linestyle"]

    fig, axarr = plt.subplots(n_features, figsize=figsize, sharex=True)
    if n_features == 1:
        axarr = [axarr]

    for axe, sig in zip(axarr, signal.T):
        color_cycle = cycle(COLOR_CYCLE)
        # plot s
        axe.plot(range(Start_time,Start_time+n_samples), sig)

        # color each (true) regime
        bkps = [0] + sorted(true_chg_pts)

        for (start, end), col in zip(pairwise(bkps), color_cycle):
            axe.axvspan(max(0, start - 0.5),
                        end - 0.5,
                        facecolor=col, alpha=alpha)

        # vertical lines to mark the computed_chg_pts
        if computed_chg_pts is not None:
            for bkp in computed_chg_pts:
                if bkp != 0 and bkp < n_samples:
                    axe.axvline(x=bkp - 0.5,
                                color=color,
                                linewidth=linewidth,
                                linestyle=linestyle)

    fig.tight_layout()

    return fig, axarr
```

Here is how the image looks with my custom display trial, which still plots with the origin as 0:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code might include zero, since you're prepending zero to the break points list:

```
           axe.axvspan(max(0, start - 0.5),
                        end - 0.5,
                        facecolor=col, alpha=alpha)
```

should probably use your `Start_time` instead of zero:

```
           axe.axvspan(max(Start_time, start - 0.5),
                        end - 0.5,
                        facecolor=col, alpha=alpha)
```